# In Actionscript what's the difference "Music/Video is loading" vs "Music/Video is buffering"?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

What is technical difference between buffering and loading ?

Say, i have a video, which is showing loader bar in progress. Then what's happening exactly ? 
Buffering or Loading ?

Thanks
V.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://support.dsny.com/cgi-local/forum/show.cgi?tpc=124&post=814#POST814:

> Loading refers to downloading the entire video to your browser cache
>   prior to playback. With loading, the video will play without any need
>   to re-buffer but there is generally some sort of wait involved.
>
> Loading can be dictated with the Autoplay parameter (LOADONLY), the
>   Prebuffer parameter, and also through VideoURL using the bandwidth
>   detection. Find out more through these links: 
>   http://clipstream.com/codegen/help/prebuffer.html
>
> http://clipstream.com/codegen/help/autoplay.html
>
> http://clipstream.com/codegen/help/videourl.html
>
> http://clipstream.com/help/web/videoclipstream/general/supportfaq_video.shtml#preloading_video
>
> Buffering refers to the small buffer that is needed to provide smooth
>   playback. If the connection speed fluctuates and/or the connection
>   speed cannot accommodate the bitrate of the video, the content may
>   need to re-buffer during playback. A pre-loaded video will not need to
>   re-buffer.
>
> The associated parameters are here:
>
> http://clipstream.com/codegen/help/videobuffersize.html
>
> http://clipstream.com/codegen/help/videoframebuffer.html
>
> They are
>   generally best left unspecified, left at their default values.